# Possible for Expo/React Native to save large amounts of encrypted data to iCloud?

Tags: react-native, expo, icloud-api

I'm developing an Expo app which stores large amounts of users private data, currently only within the app. In order to allow the user to migrate their app data between devices, we need to store this in iCloud.

I'm currently unable to find documentation or article that explains how to do this.

Is it not currently possible for Expo to save data via the iCloud API?

Answer (score 0):

there are some ways to save the data in the iCloud, one way you write ios native module
for iCloud API, then use it in the js. the detailed guide you can see [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios).

the other way is to search the third library which is used for react-native.for example:`react-native-icloudstore`. but it is old.

besides them, you can use CloudKit JS. use it in the native app webView.
you can go to the official [site](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkitjs) to learn it

In the end, if you can write native ios code, I suggest you use the first way. if you can not write it, you can search ios native relate library, then make your own 
native module for ios